# LiveServer showing blank white screen

Tags: visual-studio-code, liveserver

I have a very basic React site that I’m building. I'm using VS Code. When I run npm run start in the terminal, the site opens up properly and I can see the site. If I try to open the index.html file with LiveServer, though, it opens http://127.0.0.1:5500/public/index.html and shows just a blank white page. Then, if I go to http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html, I see a white screen stating “Cannot GET /index.html”. I’ve googled a bit to try to find an answer there, but haven’t been able to find an answer that fixes it yet. Hoping someone here might have an idea. Thanks in advance!